# Conditional filtering using CONTAINS in sql

Tags: sql, full-text-search

I have a parameter called @Param that can be null or not null.

1- I want to filter the table if @Param is not null.

2- I want to use CONTAINS

Something like:

```
    select * from MyTable
    where case when @Param is not null then contains(MyColumn, @Param)
    else null.
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this probably:

```
select * from myTable
where @param is null or contains(MyColumn, @Param)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using `AND` condition like

```
select * from MyTable
where (@Param is not null AND contains(MyColumn, @Param))
or @Param is null;
```